# Can one Kafka consumer application have Multiple DNS Addresses in bootstrap.servers?

Tags: apache-kafka

## env

kafka 2.7.1

## question

I have two dns address include each kafka broker addresses like below.
Each cluster has different zookeeper address
example:

```
# kafka cluster 1
kafka1.dns.co.kr = kafka-01:9092,kafka-02:9092,...kafka-10:9092
# kafka cluster 1 zookeeper
zookeeper = zk-01:2181,zk-02:2181,zk-03:2181/cluster-1

# kafka cluster 2
kafka2.dns.co.kr = kafka-11:9092,kafka-12:9092,...kafka-20:9092
# kafka cluster 2 zookeeper
zookeeper = zk-01:2181,zk-02:2181,zk-03:2181/cluster-2
```

Assuming that there is a topic that receives the same message in each cluster,
**If I register two dns addresses in bootstrap.server, will a consumer group be created in each cluster?**

example:

```
bootstrap.servers = kafka1.dns.co.kr:9092,kafka2.dns.co.kr:9092
```

Comment: I tested my question. If the connection from the first dns is successful, the second dns doesn't seem to try connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible with the Apache Kafka clients. A client only connects to a single cluster.

The preferred way to have data in both clusters is to set up mirroring between them. For more details, see the [Geo Replication section](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#georeplication) on the Kafka website.